# React - Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the value of input after submitting the form but code gives me the error - 'Form submission canceled because the form is not connected'. I know that if I change the button type from submit to button it will work, but I need submit method because on button click the other action is written and dont want to write code inside onclick function

```js
    updateItem(e) {
        // console.log(this.input.value);
        console.log(2222222222);
        e.preventDefault();

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <form onSubmit={this.updateItem}>
                    <input className='input'
                        type="text"
                        defaultValue={this.props.defValue}
                    // ref={(value) => {
                    //     this.input = value
                    // }}
                    />
                    <button type="submit" 
                            className='submitButton' 
                            onClick{this.props.editItem}>Update
                     </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 32):

I think all of these answers are wrong!. Here is what you should do.

since your form will be submitted with the onSubmit action then this type="submit" is what it is looking for within the form. Adding multiple buttons will trigger this warning since multiple actions are happening within the form. To fix that all you need to do is define a type to the 2nd or any other buttons ex type="button" this will fix your problem and you can add as many buttons as you like. Here is a full example.

1- Button #1

```
<button type="submit">My submit button</button>
```

!! The button having `type="submit"` must not have an `onClick` handler otherwise the error will remain. This button is tied directly to the form's `onSubmit` event

2- Button #2 to infinity

```
<button type="button">My 2nd action</button>
```

This one can have any standalone standard behaviour.

I hope it helps anyone having this issue.

Comment: Yeap, this answer is correct, it helped me <3

Comment: Right oddly enough I had to specifically type all buttons within the form to type='button', you would think that's the default type.

Comment: I only have one button on the form so... And the weird thing is even though I get this warning in the console log, it still actually submits the form correctly.

Comment: Holy cow, I've been looking for a reason why my submit button wouldn't actually trigger the submit. Getting rid of my onClick did the trick.

Answer (score 12):

Same error, but now with 2 buttons (in a Login form) :

```
<Button primary id="button_submit" type="submit">Log in</Button>
<Button onClick={onClickForgotPassword}>Forgot your password?</Button>
```

The onSubmit looks like this:

```
const onSubmit = data => {
    props.onLoginStart(data);
};
```

And the onClickForgotPassword was initially like this:

```
const onClickForgotPassword = () => {
    history.push('/auth/forgotpassword');
};
```

I also got the same error.

Solved it by adding the event.preventDefault to the onClickForgotPassword:

```
 const onClickForgotPassword = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        history.push('/auth/forgotpassword');
 };
```

And now the message is gone.

Comment: The reason this works is because by default any <button> will submit the form. Alternatively (and probably better) you could add `type="button"` to the forgotten password button

Comment: @Andy your comment was a good reminder that a button without a type is automatically defaulted to type=submit

Answer (score 11):

your form have an onSubmit handler, having a button with type='submit' and onClick is wrong, remove onClick prop and let the form onSubmit handler do submission

Answer (score 7):

what you want to do with this condition. because if you make that button type submit then onclick is not worthy. because form submit function will trigger. so you should do one thing. either remove onclick from that button or write both code in one function.

```
   <form onSubmit={this.updateItem}>
       <input className='input' type="text"defaultValue={this.props.defValue} />
       <button type="submit" className='submitButton'>Update</button>
   </form>

   updateItem = (event) => {
       //do your onsubmit work

       // do your button click work
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button"> SUBMIT </button>
```

In my own case, I prevented the default form behavior on submit so I can use my custom handler while still getting this error. My case is different because it wouldn't be good practice to still give my button the type of "submit" if it isn't actually "submitting the form". I ended up giving the type button, which I previously assumed was the default, and I stopped getting the warning. I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

This happened when I had a button with type='submit' and an onClick event.

```
<button type='submit' onClick={() => changeInput((prev) => !prev)} >Submit</button>
```

To **fix**,
extract the onClick to a handler above

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    changeInput((prev) => !prev)
  }
```

```
 <button type='submit'>Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Must do Form As this ..**

```
  <form onSubmit={this.UpdateVal}>
                    <input type='text' ref={(v)=>{this.input=v}} defaultValue={this.props.details.name} />
                    <button type='submit'>Update Course</button>
                </form>

 UpdateVal=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
          this.props.onEdit(this.input.value,this.props.Index);
          this.toggelIsEdit()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the form already listens to the submit event, you do not need to listen to the event on the button type = 'submit'. Let's remove the onClick event on the submit button

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).