# Saving data to database and conditional rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, asynchronous, async-await, onclick

I am having trouble saving data to a database and then conditionally rendering the components in react.

I want to display a message box, save the message to a database, and then remove the message box and display a `thank you` message.

For context this is react code in a `next.js` framework.

User navigates to the contact page at `contact/index.js`. The default function is

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import style from '@/styles/general.module.css';

export default function MessageFlow () {

  const [isSubmitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
    
    return (
        <>
            {
            isSubmitted ? (
              <p className={style.centerText}>Thank you. We will be in touch.</p>  
            ) : (
              <>
                <Messageform
                  isSubmitted={false}
                  onShow={() => setSubmitted(true)}
                  />     
              </>
            )
          }
        </>
    );
}
```

In the same file above `<Messageflow />` is `<Messageform />` which is

```
function Messageform({ onShow }) {

    return (
      <>
        <h1 className={style.centerText}>
                Contact
        </h1>
           <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
               <textarea type="text" id="messageText" className={style.messageBox} placeholder=" General feedback"/>
               <br></br>
               <button type="submit" onClick={onShow} className={style.greenButtonCont}>Submit</button>
           </form>
      </>
    ) 
  }
```

And above this is `handleSubmit` as

```
const handleSubmit = async (note) => {

    note.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        noteData: note.target.messageText.value
    }
    const JSONdata = JSON.stringify(data)
    const endpoint = '/api/messageForm'
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      }, 
      body: JSONdata,
    }
    await fetch(endpoint, options);
}
```

So here's the issue: with the code exactly as written, the message box disappears and `Thank you. We will be..` appears, but the message is not saved to the database. The error `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected    contact:1` displays in the browser dev tools.

One answer on S.O. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053775/getting-error-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected) talks about manipulating the DOM, but React specifically says not to touch the DOM. Also, this is just simple form submission, so I don't think you need to touch the DOM for that.

The other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834504/react-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected) talks about how you should not have an `onClick` handler on the button where you have `type="submit"`.

I *do* have an `onClick` handler on my button that has `submit` because that is where I update `isSubmitted` state to `true`. Updating `isSubmitted` is what causes the message box to disappear and the `Thank you` message to appear.

I've tried to update `isSubmitted` within `handleSubmit` but this is where it gets complicated.

If I simply pass in `isSubmitted` like `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(isSubmitted)}>` and place `setSubmitted(true)` within the `const handleSubmit = async (note) => ..` function then I get a runtime error of

```
TypeError: note.preventDefault is not a function
```

I think this is because `isSubmitted` is not an event object, so you can't do note.preventDefault on that.

I've also tried to destructure the arguments in both the `<form ..` part and the `const handleSubmit = async` part and use different combinations such as

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit({ isSubmitted })>
...
const handleSubmit = async ({isSubmitted})
```

but results `ReferenceError: note is not defined`.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit({ isSubmitted })>
...
const handleSubmit = async ({note, isSubmitted})
```

results `TypeError: note.preventDefault is not a function`.

Tried dummy variable

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit({ _a, isSubmitted })>
...
const handleSubmit = async ({note, isSubmitted})
```

results `ReferenceError: _a is not defined`.

When I delete `onClick={onShow}` from `<button type="submit"..` the message *does* save to my database; but the message box stays there and no `thank you` message appears.

I tried moving everything to `onClick` but read that you [shouldn't use](https://medium.com/@everdimension/how-to-handle-forms-with-just-react-ac066c48bd4f) a button `onClick` function to submit form data because then you're not able to respond to submit events. I think that's a similar issue when I try to pass in `isSubmitted` to `handleSubmit`. It makes `note` no longer an event.

So how do I save the message, update the state, remove the message box, and then display the `thank you` message? Seems I need both `handleSubmit` and `onSubmit`, but both together is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. First issue if you want to pass any arguments to eventHandler function like in your case `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(isSubmitted)}>`
   you are supposed to give just a function name (just handleSubmit without parentheses) and then later when form is submitted event object will be passed to this function. That's why in handleSubmit function expression you accept this argument as note. Or if you want to pass your own arguments you need to do the following `<form onSubmit={(note) => handleSubmit(note, isSubmitted)}>`
   here you are passing an arrow function and not calling it immediately. Then you can use whatever argument you passed in handleSubmit function.
2. Second issue, you are right you don't need a click handler on the button to update state. State is supposed to be updated only after the message is saved to database. If I understand correctly you can try:

- remove onClick from the button
- `<form onSubmit={(note) => handleSubmit(note, onShow)}>` pass onShow function to handleSubmit

```
const handleSubmit = async (note, onShow) => { 
    //saving to db here
    onShow();
    //calling onShow will set Submitted to true;
}
```

Comment: For the record I was able to solve this. I tried to do `<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(note, isSubmitted)}>` but then I had to define `note` within `Messageform` and I didn't know how to define it. The thing about `note` needing to be the event object was tripping me up. I ended up putting everything in one giant component and it worked. Not sure if there is a better way..

Comment: Yes, there is. I have a mistake in my answer. It's supposed to be <form onSubmit={(note) => handleSubmit(note, isSubmitted)}> note (event) will be passed to the arrow function as default argument and then will be available in handleSubmit function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `setSubmitted` directly to `Messageform` and then directly to `handleSubmit`, as that is what updates the boolean.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import style from '@/styles/general.module.css';

const handleSubmit = async (note, setSubmitted) => {

  note.preventDefault();
  const data = {
      noteData: note.target.messageText.value
  }
  const JSONdata = JSON.stringify(data)
  const endpoint = '/api/messageForm'
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    }, 
    body: JSONdata,
  }
  await fetch(endpoint, options)
    .then(setSubmitted(true));
}

function Messageform({setSubmitted}) {

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={style.centerText}>
              Contact
      </h1>
         <form onSubmit={(note) => handleSubmit(note, setSubmitted)}>
             <textarea type="text" id="messageText" className={style.messageBox} placeholder=" General feedback"/>
             <br></br>
             <button type="submit" className={style.greenButtonCont}>Submit</button>
         </form>
    </>
  ) 
}

export default function MessageFlow () {

const [isSubmitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  
  return (
      <>
          {
          isSubmitted ? (
            <p className={style.centerText}>Thank you. We will be in touch.</p>  
          ) : (
            <>
              <Messageform
                setSubmitted={setSubmitted}
              />     
            </>
          )
        }
      </>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).